# Login failed for user DefaultApp pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

I am working on a local DotNetNuke site, and all goes well. But after installing a custom module I created, in which I use Linq 2 Sql.
Suddenly I get a module load exception

> "The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS
>   APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'".

The site itself is working fine, the connectionstrings in my web.config files all use SQL-Logins, so it seems, somehow, my module chooses to use integrated security over my configured security.

I tried fixing my connectionstrings, editing the web.config and resaving.

I also tried giving the "DefaultAppPool" rights to the Database, and tried running it under LocalSystem. These both work, but are not the way it should work. The module should be installable on every configuration, regardless of the security.

Comment: Try adding `<clear />` before your connection strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply! But i found out i did not actually pass any connectionstring to my linq2sql databasecontext. By passing it, i got it to work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much DotNetNuke, but from what I see here, seems like something is accessing the SQL server using default authentication which is windows based, and the user running your application is the application pool name, in your case, it is IIS APPPOOL/DefaultAppPool, the easiest fix is to go to iis -> application pools -> find your application pool used in application -> click it and then click 'Advance Settings' in Actions panel. Find 'Identity' property and change it to localsystem. or you could grant permission to the user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' for the given database.

Also you would still need to check why the connection string is not used.

Please mark as solution if it solve your problem.

Comment: I want the application to run under Application Pool Identity because of security reasons.. And the module needs to be installable for every DotNetNuke environment regardless of the configuration. I have tried your solution before (i'll update my question) and it does fix it, but not the way i want it.